# jQuery/Bootstrap - Twitter Bootstrap Modal Opening On Page Load?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Twitter Bootstrap's Modal plugin, it all is working, and console is showing no javascript errors, but my issue is that its opening when the page loads? I close the modal, then can re open it no problem, but it just keeps opening when ever I reload the page. Here is my markup

**HTML**
Launch modal

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-    labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-header">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
  <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
</div>

   <div class="modal-body">
     <p>One fine body…</p>
   </div>

  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
     <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
   </div>
  </div>
```

**Javascript**

Pretty simple really :P,

```
 <script>
 $('#myModal').modal()  
 </script>
```

Comment: Hey I had this happen too. I was following a tutorial and used both the HTML markup for calling it AND the jquery call for the div id. Once I killed the jq call, it loaded fine with HTML markup. Could this be an issue you are running into?

Comment: Yes, you don't need the javascript call if you use the correct markup for the modal and its trigger. That's one of the great features of bootstrap - **dynamic** behavior through **static** markup. Calling `$('#myModal').modal()` effectively tells the modal to show right now rather then on click.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('#myModal').modal('hide')
```

try this

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals

Comment: This still launched it upon page load. I also tried making the #myModal's display to none, still on page load.

Comment: what about $('#myModal').modal('hide') ?

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a bunch, they really should tell you to hide it :p all they say is .modal(options) -_- lol Thanks again man.

Comment: By default it should be hidden if you used the sample from the live demo.  You've got something else interfering if it isn't and you did.

Comment: Just don't call `$('#myModal').modal()` on page load, that's why its shown... the default behavior when you call .modal() is `show:true`

Comment: @JOBG I didn't know that.  I tend to use the html markup to handle the components and as such don't often need to attach the widgets myself.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, calling `$('#myModal').modal()` tells the modal to show right now rather then on click. You should simply **remove that call altogether**.

If you use the correct markup for the modal and its trigger you don't need the javascript call at all. That's one of the great features of bootstrap - you get **dynamic behavior** through **static markup**.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use any javascript if you do not want your modal to show in page load just use the below code to create a simple modal in Bootstrap

```
   <!-- Button trigger modal -->
   <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
     Launch demo modal
   </button>

   <!-- Modal -->
   <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
     <div class="modal-dialog">
       <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
           <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
           <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-body">
           <h1>Hello World!</h1>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-footer">
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
         </div>
       </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
     </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
   </div><!-- /.modal -->
```